# How can I reattach the current JavaScript event to a different element?

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

I'm attempting to intercept a JavaScript event, and `preventDefault`, to display a warning modal. If the user chooses to accept the warning, then they click 'Continue' and carry on doing what they were doing. There are multiple possible events that this could occur for though, so I thought the best way to handle it would be to just attach the current event to the 'Continue' button.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$(document).on('click', 'nav.pagination a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;

  var checkedBoxes = $('.checkbox-pagination-warning:checked');

  if(checkedBoxes.length > 0) {
    $('.checked-box-warning-modal').modal("open");
    // This is where I would attach the event to this button:
    //
    // $('.checked-box-warning-modal a.continue')
  } else {
    $(this).unbind("click");
  }
})
```

For context, I am warning the user that there are checked checkboxes on the page before they navigate or paginate away.

Also the pagination is handled by Stimulus.

This is an example of the HTML:

```
<nav class="pagination">
  <a href="/entities/1?signatories_page=1" class="pagination-first-page" data-action="click->entities--add-existing-signatories#onPaginate">
    1
  </a>

  <span class="pagination-current-page">
    2
  </span>
</nav>
```

So how can I attach the event, which I ran `preventDefault` on, to the 'Continue' button, so that the event continues as if nothing happened?

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: can you add the HTML/snippet to make your question clear? that would help addressing the issue faster.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman I've added the HTML

Comment: @brk the question is how can I reattach the current JavaScript event to a different element? If you tell me specifically which part is not clear then I might be able to clarify for you.

Comment: @brk I tried to clarify the question by adding the last line, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have an error when defining the data-action here:

```
  <a href="/entities/1?signatories_page=1" class="pagination-first-page"click->entities--add-existing-signatories#onPaginate">
1
```

[update]
So I think you could prevent the paginate link action with event.preventDefault(). Then, you would trigger a global event that you would capture in a top controller. You would pass the current pagination link (event.target) to this new event that you will capture in the new controller.

Something like:

```
  <!-- this controller will handle showing the modal when asked -->
  <div data-controller="main" data-action="recheck@document->main#checkWithModal">

    <!-- this is the controller that captures the click on pagination links -->
    <div data-controller="pagination"></div>
  </div>


  ----- javascript

  You would use this to dispatch the event

  document.dispatchEvent(new Event('recheck', {bubbles: true, detail: { existing event target here }}))
```